# Why are the form DOM object values not being updated in this code?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using javascript to generate a password checksum using the built-in `SubtleCrypto.digest()` function. This function returns the result as a `promise` object which is then passed to an inline function that converts the result to a text representation of the hex bytes. The problem is that the inline text conversion function `digToHex()` is not updating the hidden fields in the DOM which are then submitted to the server in a POST request.

The function is called via an `onclick()` event attached to the button on the form. It reads the password input typed in by the user on the form and passes that to the `digestMsg()` function for generating the hash.

Please note that I am aware of the security issues around `SHA-1`. At present this is proof of concept only.

I have observed the output in Chrome developer tools, both on the console and network tab. I have also monitored the incoming request on the server (an IOT device). The submitted values are always null. The `digToHex()` function seems to be generating a hash because the hash does appear as the value of `chk.value` in the console tab. As can be seen from the code, I have tried assignments and form submission both outside and inside the context of the `digestMsg()` promise handler.

```
function reboot() {
    var msg = document.querySelector('#pwd1').value;

    // Test purposes only
    var opt = document.querySelector('[name = "opt"]');
    var chk = document.querySelector('[name = "chk1"]');
    // Test purposes only

    digestMsg(msg).then(result=>{
        var opt = document.querySelector('[name = "opt"]');
        var chk = document.querySelector('[name = "chk1"]');
        opt.value = 3;
        chk.value = digToHex(result);
        // document.querySelector('form').submit();

    console.log(opt.value);
    console.log(chk.value);

    });
    // form.submit();

    alert("Result: " + opt.value + " - " + chk.value);
}

function digToHex(buf) {
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(buf);
    const hexCodes = [...bytes].map(value => {
        const hexCode = value.toString(16);
        const padHexCode = hexCode.padStart(2, '0');
        return padHexCode;
    });
    return hexCodes.join('');
}

function digestMsg(msg) {
    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    const data = enc.encode(msg);
    return window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', data);
}
```

When either of the two `sumbit()` lines were uncommented, `null` values were received on the server but Chrome developer tools shows the correct values on the console output. Further investigation of the network output tab in developer tools confirms that null values are actually being transmitted. I would expect to see `"opt"` with a value of `3` and `chk1` with value containing the hash.

This is the HTML that calls the code:

```
<form method="post" action="/admin">
<input name="chk1" value="" hidden/>
<input name="chk2" value="" hidden/>
<input name="opt" value=0 hidden/>
<table>
<tr><th>Current password:</th><td><input id="pwd1" type="password">        </input></input></td>
<tr><th>New password:</th><td><input id="pwd2" type="password"></input></input></td>
<tr><th>Confirm new password:</th><td><input id="pwd3" type="password"></input></input></td>
<tr><th></th><td align="right"><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Change" onclick="change()"/></td></tr>
<tr><th></th><td><br></td></tr>
<tr><th>Defaults</th><td align="right"><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Reset" onclick="reset()"/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Restart WiFi</th><td align="right"><input type="button" class="btn" value="Reboot" onclick="reboot()"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Further testing as per Marius shows that the code does actually work with a static html page. The problem would therefore appear to be related to the way I am dynamically loading the html for each form. I attach the html for the main (parent) page below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AR488 WiFi Configuration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AR488wifi.css">
<script defer src="AR488wifi.js"></script> 
</head>
<body onload="getPage('seeStat.html')";>
<div class="mpage">
<div class="headr">AR488 WiFi Configuration</div>
<div>
<ul>
<li id="mStat" class="active"><a onclick="getPage('seeStat.html')">Status</a></li>
<li id="mGen"><a onclick="getPage('cfgGen.div')">General</a></li>
<li id="mWifi"><a onclick="getPage('cfgWifi.div')">WiFi</a></li>
<li id="m488"><a onclick="getPage('cfg488.div')">GPIB</a></li>
<li id="mAdm"><a onclick="getPage('cfgAdm.div')">Admin</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="cfgPage" class="conf">
</div>
<div>
<hr>
<table class="foot"><tr>
<td>AR488 WiFi ver: 0.00.00</td>
<td>Firmware ver: 0.00.00</td>
</tr></table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML that goes along with this. Note that if the field is disabled, the value will not be passed during form submission.

Comment: The hidden fields must also be within the form element being submitted.

Comment: How exactly are you calling `reboot`? Do you prevent the default action - submitting the form before your promise fills it?

Comment: That isn't how you create hidden fields.  It's `<input type="hidden" ... />` I'm guessing you have some CSS that uses a "hidden" attribute and hides the field from the DOM.

Comment: I am calling reboot() simply from a button control using the onclick() event. I have now added the HTML to show this. I appreciate that the event handler can be added to the javascript.

Comment: Amy, no, there is no CSS attribute, just the word 'hidden' added to the HTML definition of the field. I guess the standard probably changed a very long time ago, but the old style still works! I have changed this to type="hidden" to comply with current standards. Having then tested this, it unfortunately didn't seem to resolve the problem. Thanks for drawing it to my attention though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. I've copied what you have and added some HTML to simulate this. Make sure the fields aren't disabled.

```js
reboot();

function reboot() {
    var msg = document.querySelector('#pwd1').value;

    // Test purposes only
    var opt = document.querySelector('[name = "opt"]');
    var chk = document.querySelector('[name = "chk1"]');
    // Test purposes only

    digestMsg(msg).then(result=>{
        var opt = document.querySelector('[name = "opt"]');
        var chk = document.querySelector('[name = "chk1"]');
        opt.value = 3;
        chk.value = digToHex(result);

    console.log(opt.value);
    console.log(chk.value);

    });

}

function digToHex(buf) {
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(buf);
    const hexCodes = [...bytes].map(value => {
        const hexCode = value.toString(16);
        const padHexCode = hexCode.padStart(2, '0');
        return padHexCode;
    });
    return hexCodes.join('');
}

function digestMsg(msg) {
    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    const data = enc.encode(msg);
    return window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', data);
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="pwd1" value="test" />
<input type="text" name="opt" />
<input type="text" name="chk1" />
```

Comment: I appreciate the point about disabled fields, but I can confirm that the fields are hidden only, not disabled. I have now added the HTML to the original post. One thing to note is that the HTML form fetched and loaded into a div.innerHTML when a menu link on the parent page is selected. In this way, 4 different configuration pages can be selected.

Comment: I just copied your test (thank you for taking the trouble to do that BTW) by wrapping the HTML code I posted above with <html></html> tags and adding a header section with links to the same javascript and CSS. I just tested it and it works! Evidently the problem must have something to do with the way I am dynamically loading HTML code using innerHTML. I have added the HTML for the parent page to the original post. The question now becomes why my code mis-behaves when I dynamically load the HTML in that manner? Could it be something along the lines of what Bergi has said?

Comment: I see the updated HTML.

There are some malformed element tags in your html. Your input fields should be self closing `<input />` and not `<input></input>`>

I also see that you have 2 closing tags for each input. This could be breaking your form.

What method are you using to create these HTML Elements?

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. I will make the necessary corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution!

In my original code I was using querySelector() to obtain a reference to the form object which was immediately passed to submit but **after** processing was done:

```
document.querySelector('form').submit();
```

The form was being submitted with "opt" set to '0' - a numeric value that I had specifically set - not null or undefined, so this command appeared to be creating a reference to the original unmodified form which was then immediately submitted.

I experimented by creating a reference to the form in the context of the digestMsg() handler **before** processing took place with:

```
var formObj = document.querySelector('form');
```

After processing the form and updating values it was then submitted with:

```
formObj.submit();
```

This time, the form submitted with the correct updated values. The adjusted code (minus various test alerts) now looks like this:

```
function reboot() {
    var msg = document.querySelector('#pwd1').value;
    digestMsg(msg).then(result=>{
        var formObj = document.querySelector('form');
        var opt = document.querySelector('[name = "opt"]');
        var chk = document.querySelector('[name = "chk1"]');
        opt.value = 3;
        chk.value = digToHex(result);
        formObj.submit();
    });
}
```

I would be interested to know WHY the first command created a reference to the original modified form and did not take into account the updated values? In both cases things seem to happen in the same order - the form is loaded into the browser, the values are updated and the form is submitted. Also, why did the original version did work with a static HTML page but not with a dynamically loaded form? If anyone has an explanation I would be eager to hear it.

In the meantime, thanks for the helpful comments which have helped me focus my thinking and arrive at a solution.

The above is just proof of concept and further validation and adjustments will be required to achieve an actual working form.